# Reusing mongoose existing schema model from one file to schema model from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

**I am building a web application in Node with two different types of user. And both of them will have common as well as different properties.
The problem is I am unable to use the common mongoose schema model in another model.**

*user.js is the common model with the following schema :*

```
//Requiring Mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Creating a variable to store our Schemas
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


//Create User Schema and Model
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Email Field is required'],
        unique:true,
        match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Name field is required']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your password']
    },
    phoneNo: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Phone No is required']
    }

//Create a user model which is going to represent our model in the database 
   and passing our above-created Schema
    const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

    //Exporting Models
    module.exports = User;
```

Now I want to use the same UserSchema in another model file rider.js with another property familyNo
I have tried following way but it failed.

```
 //Requiring Mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Importing user Schema to remove the code redundancy
const userSchema = require('./user');

//Creating a variable to store our Schemas
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Driver Schema and Model
const RiderSchema = new Schema({
    user: userSchema
    familyNo: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Name field is required']
    }
});

//Create a rider model is going to represent our model in the database and passing our above-created Schema
const Rider = mongoose.model('rider', RiderSchema);

//Exporting Models
module.exports = Rider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you are not passing the schema , you are passing the user model , move your userschema in different file , and use it as schema in both the models , that will solve the problem

```
//Create a user model which is going to represent our model in the database  and passing our above-created Schema
const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

//Exporting Models
module.exports = User; // Here is the problem, User is a model not schema
```

UserSchema.js

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema([Your Common Schema])
```

User.js

```
var userSchema = require('./UserSchema');
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

OtherModel.js

```
var userSchema = require('./UserSchema');
module.exports = mongoose.model('OtherModel' , {
   property : String,
   user : userSchema
});
```

Comment: can you write the code to import the schema and use it inside another model?

Comment: Did you read my whole code? I know how to export the model but I am unable to use it in the schema.

Comment: You can use it like above

Comment: let me check it